Spring Websocket CORS issue
I have a web application served by an Angular frontend and Spring Boot backend.  They are deployed with a multi-stage Docker build on the same server. I had an issue of the websocket on Angular not connecting to the Spring websocket until I allowed CORS on the Spring websocket.
Does anyone know why this is the case? I thought that since they are on the same server, they should work even without CORS.
Here's my code:
Angular:
  onConnect(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log("Connecting...")
      this.ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${window.location.host}/websocket`)
      this.ws.onopen = this.onWebSocketOpen.bind(this)
      this.ws.onmessage = this.onWebSocketMessage.bind(this)
      this.ws.onclose = this.onWebSocketclose.bind(this)
      this.ws.onerror = (error) => console.error(error)
      resolve(this.ws)
    })
  }

Spring Boot:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Value("${webapp.host.url}")
    private String hostUrl;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/websocket");
                .setAllowedOrigins(hostUrl);      
    }
}

When CORS was not set, the Angular websocket connection failed with an close stats of 1006, reason ''. However, Postman is able to connect.

Connecting with Postman is not an issue because it targets/tests the backend directly.
However, if your Angular frontend app encounters CORS issues when calling the backend, please verify the origins (names) of both your frontend application and backend.
A scenario that comes to mind, which I've encountered in practice, involves serving both frontend and backend from the same Docker container. You might have the frontend app accessible via a different URL than localhost, such as app.test for convenience. When you access your frontend app at that specific URL, during the preflight check, the request originates from test.app and targets your backend Spring app within the container, which is usually bound to localhost:8080.
This could be one scenario; I'm not sure if it's applicable to your case.

Thanks for your input! However, my app was deployed on Railway, so in that case, both frontend and backend would be using the same origin, yes? Please correct me if I'm wrong, am pretty new to all this.

not necessarily for example CORS could be caused with differnt ports also if both of your applications are using name localhost but they have different ports CORS issue can arise.
And this deployment on railway has another layer of compexity which can effect CORS issue, for example i suppose your link on railways goes over https ?  while your docker could be serving http (keep in mind i have not used railway so i can not say for sure)
